# A list of all irreducible 4-dimensional real representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

I need a reference to a complete list of all
faithful real 4-dimensional irreducible representations
of real Lie algebras.

The list itself is not very hard to obtain.
Using the Levi decomposition,
it's possible to see that the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g
\subset\mathfrak{sl}(4, {\Bbb R})$ which does not
fix a proper subspace has to be reductive.
Then (up to a center acting by constants and/or 
by rotations with constant angle),
$\mathfrak g$ is a semisimple subalgebra
of $\mathfrak{sl}(4, {\Bbb R})=\mathfrak{so}(3,3)$.
The list of such subalgebras (I think) is
$\mathfrak{so}(1,2)=\mathfrak{sl}(2, {\Bbb R})$,
$\mathfrak{so}(3)$, $\mathfrak{so}(2,2)=
\mathfrak{so}(1,2)\times \mathfrak{so}(1,2)$,
$\mathfrak{so}(4)=\mathfrak{so}(3)\times \mathfrak{so}(3)$,
$\mathfrak{so}(1,3)=\mathfrak{sl}(2, {\Bbb C})$,
$\mathfrak{so}(2,3)=\mathfrak{sp}(4, {\Bbb R})$,
$\mathfrak{sl}(4, {\Bbb R})=\mathfrak{so}(3,3)$.
It can be (probably) obtained by removing some vertices of
the Dynkin diagram of $A_3$ and using the arcane technique of coloring the remaining vertices to obtain the real forms. All in all, it's a pain.

I am sure there is a reference somewhere
to this list (also I might have missed some
algebras). I would be much grateful for all pointers.

Comment: I think it's recommendable in such a list to separate the 3 cases: centralizer is $\mathbf{R}$ (= absolutely irreducible case), centralizer is $\mathbf{C}$, centralizer is $\mathbf{H}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A complete list of semisimple subalgebras of $\mathfrak{sl}(4,\mathbb{R})$ seems to be available here: http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/jmath/2016/2570147.pdf

Comment: Million thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your list of semisimple subalgebras is not quite complete. You are missing (at least)
$\mathfrak{sl}(3,\mathbb R)$ and $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)\times \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)=\mathfrak{so}(2,2)=\mathfrak{so}(2,1)\times \mathfrak{so}(1,2)$. See Marcel Berger
*Les espaces symétriques noncompacts*, 1957, MR0104763.

Comment: $sl_3$ does not act irreducibly in dimension 4 (but indeed $so(2,2)$ does).

Comment: many thanks! I would modify the question

Comment: I have read (cursorily) Berger's paper, and did not find anything which was helpful, but it's 94 pages long. Could you be so kind to point it more precisely. The paper is here:  http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=ASENS_1957_3_74_2_85_0 Many thanks!